# OAuth 2.0 Android redirect_uri issue

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, http-redirect, malformedurlexception

I am trying to authenticate in my app using oauth 2.0 with custom redirect_uri

https://url&redirect_uri=com.A.B.C://redirect

It works fine on most of the Android phones. However, on few Android phones like OnePlus2, LG K8 V I am getting following exception while making HttpUrlConnection.

MalformedUrlException: Unknown Protocol: com.A.B.C

How should it be handled in these devices ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the uri I can see is the custom protocol you are passing with the `redirect_uri` parameter.

**Should be like** : https://url&redirect_uri=customProtocol://redirect

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Same works in other Android devices. Same url.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information it's hard to say what's wrong. However, under the assumption this is actually a URI parser bug on said devices you could try a workaround like encoding the colon character (as `%3A`) like so:

https://example.com?redirect_uri=com.my.scheme%3A//redirect

That could help to avoid these parsers to misread the URI.